# Complex MySQL queries with multiple tables

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

**1. Student Table**

[image: Student Table]

**2. Subject Table**

[image: Subject Table]

**3. Exam Table**

[image: Exam Table]

**4. Mark Table**

[image: Mark Table]

**5. Project Table**

[image: Project Table]

**6. Daily Mark Table**

[image: daily Mark Table]

**Result Table**

Suppose i have **subjectID** and **classID** for search. Then below example result will be show using above database table :

[image: result table]

Exam could be 7th exam or 8th exam not fixed but daily and project is fixed. daily mark 6 column can be possible for each student and project mark 2 column can be possible for each student.

Anyone can help to write the sql select query ? is it possible in sql joining ?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table for how to pivot your results in MySQL, to get the exams in different columns.

Comment: The rest of it looks like you need to join with a subquery that calculates the averages.

Comment: it's very complicated query for me.... can any one to write this query. i am really confuse about exam and i can't use CASE in sql because of exam table may change the examid or add new exam